# Email reminders per week

Tags: email, scheduled-apex

Please tell me the which aspect of salesforce should I use to implement this:
I need to send reminder to the owner of a record as the end date of that record is nearing. I need to send one email per week. 
Is trigger a viable option, do we have something similar to time based workflow on a trigger?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you don't want to use time based workflow as you want to send one email, with an aggregated list within it?

Comment: if you need to send the email reminder weekly basis then I would suggest the Batch process.

Comment: @Girbot I was under the impression that we could only send one email from a time based workflow. Could you please tell me if it is possible for the time based workflow to trigger another time based workflow? So that I can send weekly reminders. Thanks

Comment: @Nilesh Batch and scheduling is a viable solution I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to time dependent Workflow rules is Scheduled Apex. You can schedule Apex jobs in:

Setup --> Monitoring --> Scheduled Jobs

Use the method for the Schedulable interface:

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger executes when there will any change in records. If you need automation then you will use Workflow, Lightning Process Builder. These tools helps you.